# How do I cancel an automation script in python outside of my IDE

Tags: python

I created a short script to help out with work today. I set it up so as long as there isn't an interrupt, my loop continues, but the second I press ctrl+c, the script should stop. It stops if I'm clicked in my editor or python shell, but if I'm in the window I want to use automation for, it does not stop. Can someone help me figure this out?

Here is the code, including modifications suggested by Hanz:

```
import pyautogui
import sys
import time

#Timer to get setup
for i in range(7,0,-1):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i)+' ')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

# i move the loop section

import keyboard

# Defining a interrupter
def interrupter():
    raise KeyboardInterrupt("[i] Interrupted!")
    # Or use exit
    # exit()

# assigning the function to your code
keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+shift+c",interrupter)

#Loop
try:
    while True:
        pyautogui.click()
        time.sleep(0.33)
        pyautogui.hotkey("enter")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()
```

Error I am receiving based modifications:

```
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keyboard\_generic.py", line 58, in process
    if self.pre_process_event(event):
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 218, in pre_process_event
    callback(event)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 649, in <lambda>
    handler = lambda e: (event_type == KEY_DOWN and e.event_type == KEY_UP and e.scan_code in _logically_pressed_keys) or (event_type == e.event_type and callback())
  File "C:\Users\myname\Coding\Pythoon\mousecontroller.py", line 17, in interrupter
    raise KeyboardInterrupt("[i] Interrupted!")
KeyboardInterrupt: [i] Interrupted!
```

Comment: You only can do `KeyboardInterrupt` at the script window not in the window you want to use automation for

Comment: @Hanz Gotcha, I'm looking online but am having trouble finding a different way of stopping my program when I'm in a different window. Do you know of a way?

Comment: i will write an answer.

Comment: i founded how!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another Python Package, `keyboard` and `mouse`.

Installation: `pip3 install keyboard mouse`

Usage:

```py
import sys
import time

#Timer to get setup
for i in range(7,0,-1):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i)+' ')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

# i move the loop section

import keyboard, mouse

#Loop
while keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl+shift+c") == False:
    mouse.click()
    time.sleep(0.33)
    keyboard.send("enter")
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this! While this does raise the exception that you created ```raise KeyboardInterrupt("[i] Interrupted!")```, I am running into a Traceback error in the threading.py package upon pressing ctrl shift C, I will comment it below

Comment: I created an Edit to the post with the error. For some reason using ctrl shift C causes that error, and the script doesnt actually stop. Weird

Comment: Wait, lemme try with pyautogui.hotkey itself

Comment: NOTE: you need to `pip install mouse`

Comment: I like this! Thanks for the help. I guess the threading error I was running into might have been due to the loops not being able to run simultaneously or something. I had an issue like that before using a listener and tkinter at the same time. Thank you!